# Python Error when importing azure-eventhub on Mac Monterey

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to import following:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventData
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub.exceptions import EventHubError
```

I get error:

```
from azure.eventhub import EventData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._common import EventData, EventDataBatch
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_common.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._utils import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from uamqp import types as uamqp_types
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from uamqp import c_uamqp  # pylint: disable=import-self
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/c_uamqp.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SASToken_CreateString'
>>> from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._common import EventData, EventDataBatch
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_common.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._utils import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from uamqp import types as uamqp_types
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from uamqp import c_uamqp  # pylint: disable=import-self
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/c_uamqp.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SASToken_CreateString'
>>> from azure.eventhub.exceptions import EventHubError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from ._common import EventData, EventDataBatch
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_common.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ._utils import (
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/eventhub/_utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from uamqp import types as uamqp_types
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from uamqp import c_uamqp  # pylint: disable=import-self
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uamqp/c_uamqp.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_SASToken_CreateString'
```

PS- I already did pip install for azure-eventhub. I am running this on Mac M1 machine, with Python: 3.10.6 and pip 22.2.2.

What needs to be fixed/imported to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

On Python 3.10 you can update to the latest uamqp package to get Apple M1 support:

```
pip install -U uamqp
```

Version 1.6.1 and above will support M1 on Python 3.10 and later

Comment: I've submitted a patch to add M1 wheels to the package, https://github.com/Azure/azure-uamqp-python/pull/335

Comment: Great news Anthony! thanks for submitting a fix :)

Comment: @anthonyshaw, any possibility to apply this patch locally until the official release includes your fix?

Comment: The latest update (October 12) has a universal2 wheel now so it should work on Python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

Try installing uamqp from source instead of wheel/binary.

Remove the eventhub and uamqp libraries first:

```
pip remove azure-eventhub
pip remove uamqp
```

Install uamqp from source first:

```
pip install --no-binary uamqp uamqp
pip install azure-eventhub
```

This worked for me on my M1. See if this works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to provide an update. My team just released a new version of the Event Hubs SDK which is using a new AMQP stack written all in Python and removes the dependency on uamqp. This allows us to support the SDK on multiple platforms with no breaking changes. You can `pip install azure-eventhub >= 5.11.0` to get the latest version. For further information please see the [announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/announcing-the-stable-release-of-the-python-event-hubs-client-library-using-pure-python-amqp-stack/) and the [readme](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub) for backwards compatibility with uamqp